# Converting Decimal to HH:MM:SS in DB2

Tags: db2, time-format

I am having trouble to convert 2.2 to HH:MM:SS in DB2. I have found a solution in SQL Server but don't know one in DB2. For example, when the decimal value is 2.2 it means 2 minutes and 2 seconds, and it should show `00:02:02`.

Thanks.

Comment: What's `HH:MM:SS` - a `VARCHAR` or a `TIME`?

Comment: Its Time. But varchar is ok  too.

Comment: So how `00:02:20` is represented in your decimal notation then, if `.2` is two seconds?

Answer (score 2):

```
> db2 "select time( to_date( '2.2', 'mi.ss' ) ) from sysibm.sysdummy1"

1
--------
00:02:02

  1 record(s) selected.
```

Comment: please provide description

Comment: These links should help: https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_9.7.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0007109.html https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_9.7.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0007107.html

Comment: Thank you very much.. Perfect. I converted 2.2 to decimal (31,2) as in some other days we could have 2.27 like that Now it works perfectly. Appreciate your help.